# Authorization of web app to Azure AD role or group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

Do we need Azure Active directory premium to do Role-based or Group based Authorization ?

I ask this question because my Azure portal is not giving me "Users" tab as mentioned in [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims#step-4--run-the-sample) link.

Answer (score 0):

Group-based access is a Basic/Premium feature as defined [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-accessmanagement-group-saasapps/).

> Using Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) with an Azure AD Premium or Azure AD Basic license, you can use groups to assign access to a SaaS application that's integrated with Azure AD.

You can only assign individual users to apps after you enable *User assignment required to access app*. But the Users tab should definitely be available though.

[image]